# Problema de encoding no Codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, codificação-de-caracteres

Utilizo Postgres como banco de dados e minha tabela está setada como UTF8.

```
ENCODING = 'SQL_ASCII'
LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

Mas quando faço uma consulta ele me retorna assim.

[image: erro enconding]

Estou fazendo apenas um `get` no banco.

```
public function get_usuario_tipo()
{
 return $this->db->get('usuario_tipo')->result_object();
}
```

E está me retornando com os acentos errados.

Minha config de DB está setada da seguinte maneira.

```
 'char_set'     => 'latin1',
 'dbcollat'     => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver aplicando utilizando.

```
utf8_encode
```

Porém creio não ser a melhor solução.